# gcloud fails to list running compute engine instances with valid project?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

For some reason, I cannot even list my running compute engine instances using gcloud...

```
NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
  - Invalid value 'MyProject'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]     
{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thought is, perhaps it wants you to pass the Project ID to the .instances.list function, and not the project name.

(Project ID can be found at the top of the 'Project Dashboard' page.)